# Room allowMainThreadQueries with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlinx.coroutines

The official Android documentation states that using `allowMainThreadQueries()` is not recommended because it could lock the UI for a long period of time and trigger an ANR.
But Kotlin coroutines gave us the possibility to perform some operation in the main thread without effectively blocking the UI.

So I'm asking: **is it safe to use `allowMainThreadQueries()` and access the database in a couroutine scope running on the main thread?** Like in the following:

```
// WITH allowMainThreadQueries()
val activityJob = Job()
val mainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + activityJob)
mainscope.launch {

    // access room database and retrieve some data

    // update UI with data retrived

}
```

Or we should stick to the old way of not allowing main thread queries and performing database queries in another thread?

```
// WITHOUT allowMainThreadQueries()
val activityJob = Job()
val defaultScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + activityJob)
val mainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + activityJob)
defaultScope.launch {

    // access room database and retrieve some data

    mainScope.launch {
        // update UI with data retrived
    }

}
```

I'm asking because the former way (with `allowMainThreadQueries()`):

- is much more readable (I can update the UI in the same coroutine context of the functions that access the database, without bearing about starting the UI updates in another coroutine scope)
- allows for simpler error handling
- makes use of only one coroutine scope (so less scopes to care about)

Comment: If database access methods marked as `suspend` then you can go with first approach, otherwise second.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need `allowMainThreadQueries()` for this to work. A scoped coroutine executs in its thread.

This is what I did not long ago:

```
@UiThread
fun getUsers(context: Context): LiveData<List<User>> {
    if (!::users.isInitialized) {
        users = MutableLiveData()
        users.postValue(MyDatabase.get(context).users().getAll())
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val usersFromDb: List<User> = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                return@async MyDatabase.get(context).users().getAll()
            }.await()
            users.value = usersFromDb
        }
    }
    return users
}
```

You can see this `getUsers()` method gets called from main thread, returning a `LiveData` (which is handy in this case). The database query happens in `GlobalScope.launch()`.

So yes, your design is one I personaly like. And one that works. But I don't think that you'll need `allowMainThreadQueries()` at all. Feel free to read (my) blog post: https://proandroiddev.com/android-viewmodel-livedata-coroutines-contraption-e1e44af690a6

Comment: I need allowMainThreadQueries() because otherwise I get runtime error, I'm not using MutableLiveData, just accessing database entities through Dao

Comment: Inside a CoroutineScope you would not need `allowMainThreadQueries()` and not receive any Exception, that was my point. And that's the code I'm using. Without `allowMainThreadQueries()`.

Comment: using global scope is not recommended unless you explicitly cancel after your work

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to access the database in your ViewModel inside `viewmodelScope`.
If you are you need to access room database from activity or fragment use

> `lifecyclescope.launch{  // access database dao functions here which are suspend in definition. }`

Or inside  the lifecycleScope  change your thread using withContext(Dispatchers.IO){}